# rqt_image_view Segmentation Fault

Tags: ros, rqt-image-view

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Howdy folks

I am using ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Since recently when I want to start rqt_image_view, nothing is happening and then I get a segmentation fault.

All other rqt gui plugins appear to work fine (like RVIZ, Bag, etc.).

I un-installed and then re-installed ROS,  but that didn't help.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Galto

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239043/rqt_image_view-segmentation-fault/) by [Galto2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/22578/galto2000/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2016-07-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fixed it:

I found that OpenCV was the culprit. I am using OpenCV 2.4.11 and in CMAKE I had configured it with QT on. I now reconfigured it without QT, rebuilt and re-installed it and now rqt_image_view is working normally.

Galto

---

Originally posted by [Galto2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/22578/galto2000/) with karma: 73 on 2016-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1